# Setting a parameter from a backing bean

Tags: java, jsf, jpa

I am build a CRUD web application using JSF and have made a add form for creating a new entity which gets persisted to the database. On a succeful save I would like the user to get navigated to a page where the details of the newly created entity will be displayed.

More in detail what I wan't to do is to create a navigation rule where on a succeful save the user gets navigated to "dilutionDetail.xhtml". Which I do using "faces-navigation.xml". And this part works fine.

My problem is that I need to pass a parameter that allows me to fetch the id of the newly created entity. Bellow is the commandButton in the add form.

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{dilution.save()}">
    <f:actionListener binding="#{dilution.prepareForSave()}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

The entity gets persisted when `dilution.save()` is called (which also returns 'saved' on success to be used in the navigation case). `dilution` is a view scoped managed bean.

Save looks like this:

```
public String save(){
    das.create(dilution);

    return "saved";
}
```

After `das.create(dilution)` has been called the `dilution` entity will have the id that I want to pass as a parameter. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to back your "dilutionDetail.xhtml" with its own `@ViewScoped` managed bean. Make it receive a view parameter, which will be the id of dilution you want to load:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{dilutionDetailBean.id}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{dilutionDetailBean.loadDilution}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

With this code you'll get your desired id set and later on, you could load it from DB with `loadDilution` method.

Now, how to navigate to it when saving? Just use implicit navigation.

```
Integer id = das.create(dilution);
return "dilutionDetail?id="+id;
```

**See also:**

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for)
- [Implicit navigation in JSF 2](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/implicit-navigation-in-jsf-2-0/)